# Spring Security - Multiple AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter's are executed even though first is successful

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have two filters added:

```
http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/cron/**")
   .hasAnyRole(APP_ENGINE_CRON, SUPER_ADMIN);

http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/**")
   .hasAnyRole(SERVICE, SUPER_ADMIN);
```

```
http
  .addFilterBefore(new AppengineCronRequestHeaderAuthFilter(authenticationManager(), "/cron/**"),
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
  .addFilterBefore(new GoogleIdTokenAuthFilter(authenticationManager(), "/**"),
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Configured authentication manager:

```
@Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(appengineCronAuthenticationProvider);
    auth.authenticationProvider(googleIdTokenAuthenticationProvider);
  }
```

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

public class AppengineCronRequestHeaderAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
  public static final String X_APP_ENGINE_CRON_HEADER = "X-Appengine-Cron";

  public AppengineCronRequestHeaderAuthFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
      String processingUrl) {
    super(processingUrl);
    this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    var appengineCronHeader = request.getHeader(X_APP_ENGINE_CRON_HEADER);
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(appengineCronHeader)
        && Boolean.TRUE.equals(Boolean.valueOf(appengineCronHeader))) {
      return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new CronAuthentication());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the first authentication provider which is successful should end the chain and proceed to execute the controller method with the provided authentication.  The first filter yields an authentication, then the second filter is executed and yields a null authentication. At this point, the controller method is NOT executed, however, I'm getting a 200 response.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. All filters in th chain will be consulted (as it doesn't need to be an authentication filter) but all other authentication filters, when implemented correctly, will back-off.

Comment: Looking at your filter the implementation (at least the one posted) is wrong, or at least you are extending the wrong filter. Your filter should be more like the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, if the header isn't present, call the next filter in the chain (instead of returning which is what the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is doing and terminating the request execution). So basically the flaw is in your filter.

Comment: Ok, making those changes... At what point does the chain decide to return a specific error response?  What accounts for 200 even with an AccessDenied exception?

Comment: Ah i see there is a default exception handling configuration which can be optionally disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems with my configuration.

1. OOB `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` does not call `chain.proceed(...)` for a null `Authentication`.  Thus if the first filter did not yield an authentication, the request would be terminated and a 200 would be returned.
2. All processing filters should be smart about whether authentication is required, i.e. check the security context for an authentication before attempting its own authentication.
3. The default `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` includes an exception handling configuration which is required to process `AccessDenied` exceptions that result from a lack of permissions after authentication in order for `AccessDenied` to terminate the request with a `403`.